# How to get available view modes per content type?

Tags: 7, entities

I am looking for an function that returns all view modes per content type. I already tried to use `mobile_theme_entity_view_mode_alter` but this function will return all available view modes for a node entity. What I need are the available view modes per node type...

any suggestions?

Comment: Yep, definitely. That answer will get you what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following function to get this information

```
$view_mode_settings = field_view_mode_settings($entity_type, $bundle);
```

example:

```
$view_mode_settings = field_view_mode_settings('node', 'article');
```